# Extract direct sub directory from path string

Tags: php, string, path, extract, relative-path

I need to extract the name of the direct sub directory from a full path string.

For example, say we have:

```
$str = "dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/filename.ext";
$dir = "dir1/dir2";
```

Then the name of the sub-directory in the $str path relative to $dir would be "dir3".  Note that $dir never has '/' at the ends.

So the function should be:

```
$subdir = getsubdir($str,$dir);
echo $subdir; // Outputs "dir3"
```

If $dir="dir1" then the output would be "dir2".  If $dir="dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4" then the output would be "" (empty).  If $dir="" then the output would be "dir1".  Etc..

Currently this is what I have, and it works (as far as I've tested it).  I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way since I find I'm using a lot of string functions.  Maybe there's some magic regexp to do this in one line?  (I'm not too good with regexp unfortunately).

```
function getsubdir($str,$dir) {
    // Remove the filename
    $str = dirname($str);

    // Remove the $dir
    if(!empty($dir)){
        $str = str_replace($dir,"",$str);
    }

    // Remove the leading '/' if there is one
    $si = stripos($str,"/");
    if($si == 0){
        $str = substr($str,1);
    }

    // Remove everything after the subdir (if there is anything)
    $lastpart = strchr($str,"/");
    $str = str_replace($lastpart,"",$str);

    return $str;
}
```

As you can see, it's a little hacky in order to handle some odd cases (no '/' in input, empty input, etc).  I hope all that made sense.  Any help/suggestions are welcome.

**Update (altered solution):**

Well *Alix Axel* had it spot on.  Here's his solution with slight tweaks so that it matches my exact requirements (eg: it must return a string, only directories should be outputted (not files))

```
function getsubdir($str,$dir) {
    $str = dirname($str);
    $temp = array_slice(array_diff(explode('/', $str), explode('/', $dir)), 0, 1);
    return $temp[0];   
}
```

Comment: did you consider using the built-in pathinfo()?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Since I only need the dirname part (which I can get directly from the dirname function) pathinfo is superfluous in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function getSubDir($dir, $sub)
{
    return array_slice(array_diff(explode('/', $dir), explode('/', $sub)), 0, 1);
}
```

---

**EDIT - Foolproof implementation:**

```
function getSubDirFoolproof($dir, $sub)
{
    /*
    This is the ONLY WAY we have to make SURE that the
    last segment of $dir is a file and not a directory.
    */
    if (is_file($dir))
    {
        $dir = dirname($dir);
    }

    // Is it necessary to convert to the fully expanded path?
    $dir = realpath($dir);
    $sub = realpath($sub);

    // Do we need to worry about Windows?
    $dir = str_replace('\\', '/', $dir);
    $sub = str_replace('\\', '/', $sub);

    // Here we filter leading, trailing and consecutive slashes.
    $dir = array_filter(explode('/', $dir));
    $sub = array_filter(explode('/', $sub));

    // All done!
    return array_slice(array_diff($dir, $sub), 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Well this has to get a +1 for brevity. :)

Comment: @Pekka: Your answer is much more descriptive, I'll upvote it but I've to "come back in about 3 hours". :P

Comment: Brilliant!  You guys are so quick!  This works perfectly except for a few specific things which I'll post in the original message.

Answer (score 2):

How about splitting the whole thing into an array:

```
$fullpath = explode("/", "dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/filename.ext");
$fulldir  = explode("/", "dir1/dir2");

// Will result in array("dir1","dir2","dir3", "dir4", "filename.ext");
// and            array("dir1", "dir2");
```

you should then be able to use [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$remainder = array_diff($fullpath, $fulldir);

// Should return array("dir3", "dir4", "filename.ext");
```

then, getting the direct child is easy:

```
echo $remainder[0];
```

I can't test this right now but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar "short" solution, this time using string functions rather than array functions. If there is no corresponding part to be gotten from the string, `getsubdir` will return `FALSE`. The `strtr` segment is a quick way to escape the percents, which have special meaning to `sscanf`.

```
function getsubdir($str, $dir) {
    return sscanf($str, strtr($dir, '%', '%%').'/%[^/]', $name) === 1 ? $name : FALSE;
}
```

And a quick test so you can see how it behaves:

```
$str = "dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/filename.ext";
var_dump(
    getSubDir($str, "dir1"),
    getSubDir($str, "dir1/dir2/dir3"),
    getSubDir($str, "cake")
);
// string(4) "dir2"
// string(4) "dir4"
// bool(false)
```